# Window blurring or smearing down

Tags: interface, opengl

When I move my mouse, the window in Blender blurs / smears down. Why is this is happening?

[image: Blurred / smeared Blender window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a configuration problem with your graphics driver.

Disable Anti-Aliasing (or all kind of filters that blur the output, Super Sampling, ...) in the driver, so that it does't override Blender's own settings.

https://developer.blender.org/T24059

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been wanting help with this and I haven't gotten any answers until now. :)